# check possible english words in long random string (C++)

Tags: c++, dictionary

Given a random string:

```
KUHPVIBQKVOSHWHXBPOFUXHRPVLLDDAPPLEWPREDDVVIDWQRBHBGLLBBPKQUNRVOHQEIRLWOKKRDD
```

How do i check if the random string contains possible english words in it?

What's the most efficient way of searching for all possible English words embedded in this string?

I already downloaded english dictionary text file.

I would like to compare the string and english dictionary text file to find the possible words.

Can anyone give some hints how to do for this?

Comment: There's a string::find(string), so you can load your random string, then iterate over words in your dictionary, and see if it finds one. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Comment: `can anyone give some code for this?` No. We are not here to code for you. If you have an actual problem with code, then post it and we'll be happy to help you. Your question doesn't fit StackOverflow's goals.

Comment: @Ninetainedo oh sorry i didnt mean to give the "actual" code for it. i meant "some good hint".

Comment: But it looks like you didn't look around by yourself before asking. Try some things and edit your post with what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the brute force approach.  After getting this method working, you can optimize later.

The brute force algorithm:

```
For each word in the dictionary,
  search the string for that word.
```

Other methods may take longer.  You will have to ask yourself, "is spending time making this algorithm more efficient worthwhile?"

For infrequent uses, the answer would be no.  As an answer to an Online Judge, maybe you will need to improve the efficiency.  If you have a lot of strings like this, then maybe you should optimize the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a DAG from the words in your dictionary and use this to search for hits. For example, if your dictionary contains the words

- auto
- autobahn
- austria

This would lead to a graph like this

```
a -> u -> t -> o -> 'hit'
      |         |
      |         |-> b -> a -> h -> n -> 'hit'
      |
       -> s -> t -> r -> i -> a -> 'hit'
```

Based on this data structurce ([here is a library for this](https://code.google.com/p/dawgdic/wiki/Readme)) you can start feeding letters starting from each position in your random string until there is no edge to follow or until you obtain a hit.

Since the DAG is not updated, this can be done in parallel by starting at different positions in your random string.

---

Here is how to build such a search structure:

```
// Inserts keys into a simple dawg.
dawgdic::DawgBuilder dawg_builder;
dawg_builder.Insert("auto");
dawg_builder.Insert("autobahn");
dawg_builder.Insert("austria");

// Finishes building a simple dawg.
dawgdic::Dawg dawg;
dawg_builder.Finish(&dawg);

// Builds a dictionary from a simple dawg.
dawgdic::Dictionary dic;
dawgdic::DictionaryBuilder::Build(dawg, &dic);

// Checks if a key exists or not.
if (dic.Contains("auto"))
  std::cout << "auto: found" << std::endl;

// Finds a key and gets its associated record.
if (dic.Find("august") < 0)
  std::cout << "august: not found" << std::endl;
```